# How can i print only letters?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a caesar cipher in javascript, I'm very new at this. I know i have to limit the ascii so that it's only letters. Because like this if we insert the letter "z" and the key "3" it won't give us "c", but something else. I've tried to search but i can't seem to understand how to do that. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 var letter=readLine("letter?");
 var key=parseInt(readLine("key?"));
 var result= letter.charCodeAt(0)+key;
 print(String.fromCharCode(result));
```

Comment: Are you doing this in NodeJS using the command line? for input?

Comment: Will your cipher be case sensitive? The solution is different if you deal with upper and lower

Comment: Yes, I'm using webstorm. And the user is supposed to insert the letter and a key.

Comment: I would like it to work either we input the letter in upper or lower case, but i cant seem to do it correctly.

Comment: See https://www.nayuki.io/res/caesar-cipher-javascript/caesar-cipher.js for a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it should work:

```
for(var i =0; i<letter.length;i++){
      print(String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(i) + key))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an outdated question but since no one has posted the answer:
To shift only letters you can use this:

```
caesarCipher = (s, k) => {

let string = s;

   string =  string.replace(/[a-z]/g, str => String.fromCharCode((str.charCodeAt(0) - 97 + k) % 26 + 97));
   string =  string.replace(/[A-Z]/g, str => String.fromCharCode((str.charCodeAt(0) - 65 + k) % 26 + 65));

  return string;
}
```